# Sum reduction with CUDA: What is N?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, sum

According to NVIDIA, [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) is the fastest sum reduction kernel:

```
template <unsigned int blockSize>
__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int *sdata, unsigned int tid) {
if (blockSize >=  64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
if (blockSize >=  32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
if (blockSize >=  16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  8];
if (blockSize >=    8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  4];
if (blockSize >=    4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  2];
if (blockSize >=    2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  1];
}
template <unsigned int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
extern __shared__ int sdata[];
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
sdata[tid] = 0;
while (i < n) { sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize];  i += gridSize;  }
__syncthreads();
if (blockSize >= 512) { if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (blockSize >= 256) { if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (blockSize >= 128) { if (tid <   64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +   64]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

However, I don't understand the "n" parameter. Any clues? I don't think it's the size of the array to reduce, since in the while loop there would be a buffer overflow.

Comment: ```n``` is the number of elements in the ```g_idata``` array. Also, it's unlikely that that particular kernel is the "fastest" reduction; that document is quite old by now.

Comment: Please note that with the NVidia Kepler architecture, the code you quoted is certainly not the fastest possible reduction. The intra-warp work can be done using the _shfl_xor instruction. See [this presentation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3174-Kepler-Shuffle-Tips-Tricks.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you've discovered a typo in the slides (it should probably be something like `while(i + blockDim.x < n)`).

If you take a look at the source code in the CUDA SDK sample ["reduction"](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#reduction), the body of the most recent `reduce6` looks like this:

```
template <class T, unsigned int blockSize, bool nIsPow2>
__global__ void
reduce6(T *g_idata, T *g_odata, unsigned int n)
{
    T *sdata = SharedMemory<T>();

    // perform first level of reduction,
    // reading from global memory, writing to shared memory
    ...

    T mySum = 0;

    // we reduce multiple elements per thread.  The number is determined by the 
    // number of active thread blocks (via gridDim).  More blocks will result
    // in a larger gridSize and therefore fewer elements per thread
    while (i < n)
    {         
        mySum += g_idata[i];
        // ensure we don't read out of bounds -- this is optimized away for powerOf2 sized arrays
        if (nIsPow2 || i + blockSize < n) 
            mySum += g_idata[i+blockSize];  
        i += gridSize;
    }
```

Note the explicit check within the `while` which prevents out of bounds access to `g_idata`. Your initial suspicion is correct; `n` is simply the size of the `g_idata` array.